# How to Remove tuples from list of tuples if exists in another one

Tags: python, tuples

```
A =[(('6X', 1),), (('6E', 4),), (('10X', 2),)]
B=['6E', '10X']
```

I would like to keep the only elements in A that have a first element that exists in B to get

```
a =[ (('6E', 4),), (('10X', 2),)]
```

Code:

```
a=[] 
for r in range(0, len(A)):
  # print(A[r][0][0])
  for k in range(0, len(B)): 
    if A[r][0][0]==B[k]: 
       a=A[r][0] 
       a.append(a)
print( a)
```

Comment: can you please help us with the code you tried so far? It is fine if it doesn't works, we can help you in fixing it

Comment: a=[]
for r in range(0, len(A)):
    
#    print(A[r][0][0])
    for k in range(0, len(B)): 
        if A[r][0][0]==B[k]:
            a=A[r][0]
          
            a.append(a)
            
print( a)

Comment: this may work but I am just looking for more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: Don't post that in the comments, post it in the question itself as formatted text

Comment: @mohamed I edited your post to include the code.

Answer (score 0):

If your example data covers all the tuple embedding possibilities then a simple list comprehension would do the trick:

```
a = [ ta for ta in A if ta[0][0] in B ]

[(('6E', 4),), (('10X', 2),)]
```

However, if you have deeper/variable levels of nesting, you would probably need a function to get to the first value:

```
def firstValue(T): return firstValue(T[0]) if isinstance(T,tuple) else T

a = [ ta for ta in A if firstValue(ta) in B ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `filter` [func](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter).
You pass a lambda expression that resolves in true/false for each value in the list. Values that resolve to `True` are passed to the output list.

```
a = list(filter(lambda x: x[0][0] in B, A))
print(a)

# Output
# [(('6E', 4),), (('10X', 2),)]
```